# why doesn't my spawn manager instantiate after checking the bool from another script?

Tags: unity, c#

This is where the bool originated

```
public bool LeftBlock = false;

void Start()
{
    shaking = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Screenshake")?.GetComponent<CamMovement>();
}
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Attack")
    {
        if (shaking != null)
        {
            shaking.ShakingTime();
            healthPoints--;
            if(healthPoints <= 2)
            {
                LeftBlock = true;
                Debug.Log("2nd Phase");
            }
            if (healthPoints == 0)
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the script where I want my object spawn

```
private SecondBad BossTwo;
  BossTwo = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SecondBoss")?.GetComponent<SecondBad>();

 void Update()
{   

    if(firstboss.FirstDied == true)
    {
        Invoke("secondspawn", 1.5f);
    }

{
    //Boss
    if (!SecondSpawnOnce)
    {
        Instantiate(SecondBoss, new Vector2(0.0048f, 0.2f), Quaternion.identity);
        SecondSpawnOnce = true;
    }
    //Normal
    if (Time.time > nextSpawnTimeSecond)
    {
        nextSpawnTimeSecond = Time.time + TimeSecondSpawn;
        Vector2 spawnTwo = new Vector2(Random.Range(1.75f, 3.7f), screenWrap.y);
        Instantiate(Secondfall, spawnTwo, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -29.541f));
    }

    if (BossTwo != null)
    {
        if (BossTwo.LeftBlock == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("ok");
            if (Time.time > nextSpawnTimeSecond)
            {
                Debug.Log("Where");
                nextSpawnTimeSecond = Time.time + TimeSecondSpawn;
                Vector2 SpawnVerTwo = new Vector2(Random.Range(-1.75f, -3.7f), screenWrap.y);
                Instantiate(Secondfall, SpawnVerTwo, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 29.541f));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Whenever you have the pattern `FindGameObjectWithTag("TagForSomeUniqueObject").GetComponent<ScriptForSomeUniqueObject>()`, it is always better to replace it with the (shorter, faster, cleaner!) `FindObjectOfType<ScriptForSomeUniqueObject()`. Never search twice when once auffices.

Comment: It also looks like you omitted some code here. Can you edit your question to provide a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example?

Comment: `firstboss.FirstDied` is as well never set to false again, you should have a boss wave somewhere once it actually spawns.